# Is it possible for me with discord.py to be able to have my bot DM someone when I mention them?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

More specifically, I would like, after I use my command prefix and whatever command I assign it to, to tell the bot to message the user I mention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If you're using [the commands extension](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/index.html), you can use a [`MemberConverter`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.MemberConverter) or [`UserConverter`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.UserConverter) to get the [`Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member) or [`User`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User) object, respectively. Otherwise, you can use the [`Message.mentions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.mentions) attribute of the [`Message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message) object to get a list of the `Member`s that were mentioned in the message. Then, you can use the [`Member.send`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.send)/[`User.send`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User.send) method to DM them.